# mapStateToProps undefined state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

First of all I know a lot of stuff in this code snippet is off, I know. I'm only trying to address the question here. For some reason my app says that it cannot read property 'todo' of undefined, and highlights todos: [...state.todos] in my Form.js mapStateToProps method. Am I not importing something that I should be here?

Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import uuidv1 from 'uuid';
import { addTodo } from '../actions';
import TodoInput from './todo-input';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addTodo: todo => dispatch(addTodo(todo))
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: [...state.todos]
})

class ConnectedForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { inputValue} = this.state;
    const id = uuidv1();
    this.props.addTodo({inputValue, id});
    this.setState({inputValue: ''});
  }

  handleToggle (e) {
    const id = parseInt(e.target.id);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: prevState.todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {...todo, done: !todo.done} : todo)
    }));
    console.log(e.target);
  }

  render() {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className='form-group'>
          <TodoInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />

          <TodoList />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Form = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (ConnectedForm);

export default Form;
```

TodoList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import { removeTodo, toggleComplete } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      removeTodo: id => dispatch(removeTodo(id)),
      toggleComplete: isDone => dispatch(toggleComplete(isDone))
    };
  };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {todos: [...state.todos]};
};

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const mappedTodos = this.props.todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <TodoItem 
      todo={todo}
      title={todo.title}
      key={index}
      removeHandler={this.props.removeTodo}
      toggleComplete={this.props.toggleComplete}
      />
    ));
    return (
      mappedTodos
    );
  }
}

const TodoList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (List)
export default TodoList;
```

Reducers

```
import { ADD_TODO, REMOVE_TODO, TOGGLE_COMPLETE } from '../constants/action-types'; 
import uuidv1 from 'uuid';

const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos,
          {
            title: action.payload.inputValue,
            id: uuidv1(),
            createdAt: Date(),
            priority: '',
            deadline: '',
            isComplete: false
          }]
    }

    case REMOVE_TODO:
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.payload)]
    }

    case TOGGLE_COMPLETE: 
    return (
      console.log(action.payload)
    )

    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Comment: Does this happen right after page load, or after some interactions with the UI?

Comment: Actually, that does not matter. Look here: `return (
      console.log(action.payload)
    )`. You might have a typo, but you're returning the result of the `console.log` function.

Comment: Oh my gosh what a catch! THANK YOU hahaha

Comment: You might want to use some JS linter to help you catch such errors while still typing. It becomes harder to see them by eye alone as the project grows

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is not that clear because you don't say where exactly the error is coming from but all in all, I can see that on the `handleToggle` in the `ConnectedForm class`, you are trying to loop over `prevState.todos` yet  in the state of that `class` you don't have any `todos` property neither did you set one anywhere in the that `class`. Therefore, you are trying to access `todo` which is actually not defined anywhere in your `state`.

Comment: I did say ` highlights todos: [...state.todos] in my Form.js mapStateToProps method.`

Comment: And also like I said in the question, I know there is a lot that wont make sense, the handleToggle class youre seeing was from before I started refactoring my code to include redux. That method does nothing and isn't bound to anything. But thanks for reminding me to take it out.

Comment: makes sense that you are now refactoring to include redux

Comment: Yeah im still pretty new to all of this. Haha